# О сопряжённости и связанности в книге "От монолита к микросервисам" С. Ньюмен

Tags: java, книги, микросервисы

Читаю книгу Сэма Ньюмена "От монолита к микросервисам" и дошёл до следующих строк(стр 36):

> Сопряженность (coupling) говорит о том, как изменение в одной вещи
> требует изменения в другой; связность (cohesion) говорит о том, как мы
> группируем родственный код. ’’Структура является стабильной, если
> связность высокая, а сопряженность низкая”.
> -Ларри Константин (Larry Constantine)
>
> Это наблюдение кажется разумным и полезным. Если у нас есть два
> фрагмента родственного кода, то связность является низкой, поскольку
> родственная функциональность распространяется на каждый из них. У нас
> также есть тесная сопряженность, поскольку когда этот родственный код
> изменяется, то должны измениться обе вещи.

Никак не могу понять, почему у двух фрагментов родственного кода связность низкая? Разве родственный код в данном случае, не код который является близким по бизнес-логике/требованиям? Например saveUser/getuser.

Аналогично не могу понять обьяснение следующих строчек

> Проблема с монолитом заключается в том, что слишком часто он является
> противоположностью того и другого. Вместо того чтобы тяготеть к
> связности и держать все вещи, которые тяготеют к одновременному
> изменению, вместе мы приобретаем и склеиваем всевозможный
> неродственный код.

В цитате выше, запятая, возможно, должна стоять после слова *вместе* , а не после *изменению*

Но ведь даже в монолите мы содержим код, связанный с бизнес-сущностями в отдельных сервисах,
т.е код, связанный с изменением юзера лежит в userService, с изменением бланков в blankService, имею ввиду, что мы не просто склеиваем всевозможный код, но и группируем его по правилам, что как раз таки и отделяет части, тяготеющие к одновеменному изменению от других частей, разве не так?
Буду рад каждому мнению.

Comment: В контексте представленных строчек, понятие "связность" относится к сгруппированности функционально связанного кода, т.е. насколько близко связаны между собой различные части кода. В данном случае, два фрагмента родственного кода имеют низкую связность, потому что родственная функциональность распространяется на каждый из них, они не находятся в единой группе или модуле.

Comment: Код, связанный с бизнес-сущностями, может быть разделен на отдельные сервисы в монолите, но если эти сервисы не являются независимыми и требуют сильного взаимодействия и изменений друг друга, то связность все равно будет считаться высокой. Идея микросервисной архитектуры заключается в том, чтобы разделить код на независимые микросервисы, где каждый из них представляет определенный функционал и имеет свою базу данных, что позволяет минимизировать связность между сервисами и уменьшать необходимость одновременного изменения разных частей системы при внесении изменений.

Comment: В предложении о монолите речь идет о том, что в монолитной архитектуре различные функциональности и компоненты могут быть тесно связаны друг с другом, в результате чего изменение одной части может потребовать внесения изменений в целый монолит. Это может привести к большим затратам на разработку и поддержку системы.

Comment: Думаю, стоит посмотреть, как написано в оригинале. Часто при переводе смысл некоторых фраз искажается.

Comment: _почему у двух фрагментов родственного кода связность низкая?_ - потому что это **два** фрагмента. А должен быть **один** для высокой связности. / Тут суть в том, что считать _фрагментом_.

Comment: Да, запятая должна быть после слова "вместе". Я оригинал на английском посмотрел.